# Spring Boot custom receive responses with HTTP OPTIONS by throw exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot, and I am trying to test a connection using HTTP OPTIONS.

My design is that I have a Service class that contains the logics for the testing.  I also have an API Controller class that implements the method from Service.

My currently understanding is that the controller can be used to respond back different HTTP statuses using exceptions.

This is the method I wrote inside the controller for this purpose:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<Void> testConnection(@RequestBody URL url) {
    try {
        ControllerService.testConnection(url);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(null);
    } catch (CredentialsException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(null);
    } catch (URLException | URISyntaxException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
    } catch (UnknownException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    } 
}
```

The way exceptions are triggered and the method testConnection() are inside the service class:

```
public static void testConnection(URL url)
        throws URISyntaxException, CredentialsException, URLException, UnknownException {

    String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user" + ':' + "password").getBytes());

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.set("Authorization", authHeaderValue);

    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    final ResponseEntity<Object> optionsResponse = rest.exchange(url.toURI(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS, new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders), Object.class);
    int code = optionsResponse.getStatusCodeValue();

    if (code == 403) {
        throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
    } else if (code == 404) {
        throw new InvalidURLException();
    } else if (code == 500) {
        throw new UnknownErrorException();
    }  else if (code == 200){
        String message = "Test connection successful";
        LOGGER.info(message);
    } 
}
```

I have created those custom exception classes.

Is this the proper way to trigger the right HTTP response inside the controller method or does Spring Boot has some other design?  If so, is my list of exceptions comprehensive enough or do I need to add more to the testConnection() method in the service class?

Comment: I think you can use some java Filter to catch the exceptions and return a response with the specific http status code for each exception. Does this help you? I have other ideas based on this too.

Comment: @Dherik Hi, thank for the input. I think Filter should work. Would I apply it in my Service class method?

Answer (score 1):

You can write ExceptionHandler for each of the Exception type, so you don't have to repeat the code or use try/ catch block at all. Just let your testConnection and other methods to throw the exception.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ExceptionHandler(CredentialsException.class)
public void credentialsExceptionHandler(CredentialsException e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), e.getMessage());
}
```

There are different ways to define and use the ExceptionHandler method. But conceptually same.